# Can someone decompile my C# app and override the protection mechanism?

Tags: c#, decompiling

If I create a C# app which has a mechanism to restrict the number of workstations accessing the database, what is stopping someone decompliling the app, changing the code for this mechanism, recompiling it and then deploying it on their systems?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61740/can-we-restrict-the-number-of-connections-to-a-database-in-sql-server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Potentially nothing, however you can increase the effort, and reduce the benefit of this sort of thing:

1. Create a simple, easy to use license system.
2. Don't overcharge
   for your product.
3. Sign your assemblies (although this can be
   removed).
4. Hide/Obfuscate the number of workstations in your code
   (e.g. use an octal number and don't make an error message easy to
   find in code).
5. Obfuscate the entire assembly (a good one will
   prevent it from being completely decompiled).

Comment: +1 for pointing out the ttoal truth. It wont work. Has not worked for  games ever since someone thought he invented copy protection, and does not work for blue ray discs either. All you can do is make it harder. OFTEN that is enough, financially.

Answer (score 3):

Yes tools like [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) can decompile your C# Program, and then [Reflector.FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) can even get your source back.

I highly recommend reading HRH Jon Skeets article here on .NET Obfuscation and Decompilation:
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/obfuscation.html

For .net (and even Java which has similar problems) there are [obfuscators](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview). Visual Studio comes with the community version of Dotfuscator, however, there is a **catch**:

The [MSIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) is regenerated with a lot of obscurity once compiled, so when a hacker decompiles it, it's hard to read. But, when there is an exception, the stack trace will also show obfuscated code so now the program is much harder to debug by you.

The paid versions have a XML Map which can map an exception to the right classes so **you** can know which class/method an error lies in.

Like Jon's article describes, its a matter of balance and no software is truly safe.

Answer (score 1):

You could [sign it with a strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4fa028b.aspx).

Comment: +1 This is relevant since this will make the original application verifiable. It won't prevent decompilation but will make people who use the application know whether it is the original version or not. It's like appending a hash of the code to the assembly. Am I right?

Comment: @user1041631: Exactly. If someone really wants to hack your code, they will most probably succeed. You can just make it a bit harder for them (witness all the hacked programs available on the internet).

Answer (score 0):

You can use obfuscator to prevent this. Obfuscator will make your byte code very tangled and unreadable, and by this it will make it reasonably hard to decompile your program and find authorization code.
But of course, as with any other program, this protection can be beaten.

Comment: An obfuscator won't stop and prevent this, it will just deter users from doing it.

Comment: Didn't I write exactly this? Or you prefer to read only first sense?

Comment: Your very first sentence says otherwise and is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the assembly strongly named by signing it.